# Update using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update my request table WHERE `assessment_status='assessed'` from the `student_assessment` and set in into not assessed but I'm getting syntax error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM request LEFT JOIN student_asse...' at line 5

```
   UPDATE 
   request
    SET 
        request.assessment_status = 'not assessed'
    FROM request
    LEFT JOIN student_assessment 
        ON student_assessment.student_id = request.id
        WHERE request.assessment_status = 'assessed'
```

Comment: Yep, a LEFT JOIN on an UPDATE is a decidedly odd thing. Even where it makes sense, it can usually be replaced by two UPDATES.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax in MySQL would be:

```
  UPDATE request r LEFT JOIN
         student_assessment sa
         ON sa.student_id = r.id
    SET r.assessment_status = 'not assessed'
    WHERE r.assessment_status = 'assessed';
```

However, this logic doesn't really make sense.  The `LEFT JOIN` is not doing anything useful.